# 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: startButton

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was doing a tutorial and got this error.

Line 3  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: startButton.

I did some research and I found someone who had excatly the same problem. He was helped in the comment section. 
the creator of the tutorial told him the following:

"Have you turned “auto-declare stage instances” on, as in the start of Part 1? Also, is your startButton inside the MenuScreen clip, and is the MenuScreen exported for ActionScript?"

Now i think i haven't auto-declared stage instances. (the other things are done, I did a double check) But it's a bit vague to me what it means, could you possible tell me how to do “auto-declare stage instances” after already having it all coded.

the link to tutorial: http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2008/10/12/avoider-game-tutorial-4/comment-page-5/#comments

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class MenuScreen extends MovieClip 
{

    public function MenuScreen()
    {

        startButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickStart );
    }

    public function onClickStart( event:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        dispatchEvent( new NavigationEvent( NavigationEvent.START ) );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
public var startButton:SimpleButton;
```

or

```
public var startButton:MovieClip;
```

to the class `MenuScreen` depending on type of `startButton` on the scene. Be sure that you gave the name `startButton` to the button instance and don't forget to assign class `MenuScreen` to the component that holds the `startButton`.